# notation meaning of real analysis

Tags: real-analysis

What does

$$E = \{r ⊆ [a,b] : [a,r] \}$$
mean in real analysis?
The section is about the compact sets,
and the whole notation is 
$$E = \{r ⊆ [a,b] : [a,r]\ \text{is covered by a finite number of the sets}\ U_a\}$$

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a strange way of writing 
$$E = \{r \in [a, b] : [a, r]\ \text{is covered by a finite number of}\ U_a\text{'s}\}$$

I agree that the $\{r \subseteq [a, b] : \dotsc\}$ notation (specifically the subset symbol) is confusing.

Answer (score 0):

$E$ is the set of real numbers $r$ between $a$ and $b$  such that there is a finite collection of sets from $\{U_a\}$ that cover the interval $[a, r]$.